# Carregar fancybox em toda a tela

Tags: fancybox

Pessoal tenho um iframe numa pagina minha que tem dentro algumas imagens. Preciso disparar o fancybox nestas imagens mas ele tem que ocupar toda a tela  da página e não o espaço total do iframe apenas.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529988/1216394) solução.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues eu tinha visto este post até estou usando ele, mas o problema é que dentro do iframe eu tenho varias imagens e preciso usar o fancybox como galeria para exibir uma foto apos a outra quando se clica nos botoes de navegação para a direita e para esquerda e este exemplo ele não carrega dinamicamente todas as imagens do grupo. Você sabe como resolver isto?